# defining a color injection to value on matrix , in image( ) R

Tags: image, r

In `image()` , how to define an injection of the colour to the value on matrix ?
I'm writing a programme to make colour chart on (x,y) coordinate-plane 
Shows the hazard ratio from a value of x-axis and y-axis.

(eg.) x-axis is for "age", and y-axis is for "blood pressure", and if the third or upper dimension (z) is there, one colour chart is made for each z unique value.

I'm trying `image()`, but it isn't what I want because the colour on chart is defined on each (x,y)coordinate-plane, so only the (x,y) effect is represented.
(the effect of z-value is treated like as intercept.)

I think that to define injection of the colour to the value in my function would solve
  this problem.

In my function , I define a matrix

```
mat.for.map[i,j] <-  exp ( yax[i] * yest 
                            + xax[j] * xest 
                             + zax * zest
                              + cat1 
                               + cat2 )
```

'xax' is sequence for x-axis
    `xax <- seq ( xlow , xup , length.out = xlen )`

'yax' is for y-axis
    `yax <- seq(ylow,yup,length.out = ylen)`

'xest' is hazard for variable-x
 'yest' is for variable-y

and I got a dataset of hazars ratio

```
hazards <- c( 0.1302 , 0.0154 , -0.0030 , 0.5971 , 0.3773
           , 0.1300 , 0.0159 , -0.0017 , 1.1522 , 0.3390
           , 0.1037 , 0.0133, 0.0121 , 1.2249 , 0.3647
            , 0.1480 , 0.0045 , 0.0034 , 1.5109 , 0.7472)

rowname1 <- c( "age" , "sbp" , "TotCho" , "DM" , "smk" )
colname2 <- c( "Stoke" , "CHD")
colname1 <- c( "men" , "women" )

array.hazards <- array(hazards, c(5,2,2))
dimnames(hazards)<- list(rowname1,colname1,colname2)
```

and if the third or upper dimention is defined 
 in argument 'z'(value) , 'zest'(hazard) and 'cat1' , 'cat2' ,
 they are added to the values in 'mat.for.map'.

THIS IS MY PROBLEM
 when I change 'z' or 'cat1' or 'cat2' ,the values in 'mat.for.map'  changes ,
 but the colours on chart does not.

---

My function is below

```
chart.make <- function(xest ,yest,
             zest, xup,xlow,xlen
            ,yup,ylow,ylen
            ,zup=NULL,zlow=NULL,zlen=NULL,
            xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,
            cat1=0,cat2=0) {

  xax <- seq(xlow,xup,length.out = xlen)
  yax <- seq(ylow,yup,length.out = ylen)
  zax <- z

  mat.for.map <- matrix(c(rep(0,length(xax)*length(yax))),
                          ncol=length(yax))
  for(j in 1:length(xax)) {
    for(i in 1:length(yax))
      mat.for.map[i,j] <- exp(xax[j]*xest+yax[i]*yest+zax*zest+cat1+cat2)
  }

  list.chart <- list(xax,yax,mat.for.map)
  names(list.chart) <- c("x","y","z")
  return (image(list.chart,col=rainbow(100),xlab=xlab,ylab=ylab,useRaster = TRUE))
}
```

For example

```
hazards <- c( 0.1302 , 0.0154 , -0.0030 , 0.5971 , 0.3773
           , 0.1300 , 0.0159 , -0.0017 , 1.1522 , 0.3390
           , 0.1037 , 0.0133, 0.0121 , 1.2249 , 0.3647
            , 0.1480 , 0.0045 , 0.0034 , 1.5109 , 0.7472)

rowname1 <- c( "age" , "sbp" , "TotCho" , "DM" , "smk" )
colname2 <- c( "Stoke" , "CHD")
colname1 <- c( "men" , "women" )

array.hazards <- array(hazards, c(5,2,2))
dimnames(array.hazards)<- list(rowname1,colname1,colname2) 

pdf("chart1.pdf")
z1 <- chart.make(
   array.hazards["sbp","women","CHD"],array.hazards["TotCho","women","CHD"]
      ,zest=array.hazards["age","women","CHD"]
      ,240,90,30
      ,279,160,6,zup=75,
      ,ylab="Total Cholesterol",xlab="Sistlic Blood Pressure"
      ,cat1=array.hazards["smk","women","CHD"])

mtext(text="CHD in women 70<age<80,smoker,DM",side=3,cex=1)
dev.off()

pdf("chart2.pdf")
z1 <- chart.make(
   array.hazards["sbp","women","CHD"],array.hazards["TotCho","women","CHD"]
      ,zest=array.hazards["age","women","CHD"]
      ,240,90,30
      ,279,160,6,zup=75,
      ,ylab="Total Cholesterol",xlab="Sistlic Blood Pressure"
      ,cat1=array.hazards["smk","women","CHD"]
      ,cat2=array.hazards["DM","women","CHD"])
mtext(text="CHD in women 70<age<80,smoker",side=3,cex=1)
dev.off()
```

As I comment at Paul Hiemstra, I'm sorry I can't show you a example of what I want ,so I present a simlified one.

```
 x <- seq(1:200,by=2)
 z <- 20


 mat1 <- matrix(x,ncol=10)
 mat2 <- matrix(x:z,ncol=10)
 mat3 <- matrix(x+z,ncol=10)

image.1 <- image(mat1,col=rainbow(100))
image.2 <- image(mat2,col=rainbow(100))
image.3 <- image(mat3,col=rainbow(100))
```

I think my problem is equal to 'image.1 is same to image.3,the effect of adding z is not reflected in colour on chart.'

Thank you very much for your time. (I'm afraid of being closed)

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you want the chart to look? At this stage I'm a bit puzzled as to what you want.

Comment: Agree with PaulH.  image() does not choose colors based on x and y values: it plots a color at each (x,y) coordinate based on the z-value at that location.  Do you mean that you have a fourth set of data which are the hazard ratio, and you want to plot a collection of images, one for each z-value?

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra Thank you for advice. I'm sorry but I can't show you an exact example because I can't make it. I present a simplified one .  My problem is equal to "image.1 and image.3 is same in this example".

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I appliciate your kindly advice.I defined matrix [i,j] as a exponential of summation of (x,y) , producted each hazard.I'm afraid my quetion was too crude so I edited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(array4hm), aes(x=X1,y=X2,fill=value))+geom_tile()+facet_grid(.~X3)
```

Comment: I appliciate your quick and elegant answer. I will try.This is my first time using ggplot2 (and ggplot).Thank you.